# NSMutable string issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am implementing a simple calculator.

Each time the user clicks digits buttons, the sender.tag is appended to a nsmutable string called displayString with is then displayed on screen.

The mutable string is initiated with size 40.

Strangely, after entering 10 digits , for example `1111111111` , the string behaves wrongly.

If you continue to click on the digit button '1', the string doesn't append '1' anymore, but another value, like, 2 or 6 ... and suddenly a number like `25469632154` appears!

Checked with the Debugger - the problem does not come from the display but from the string itself with is not correctly appended .

Could it be the `sender.tag` is not passed correctly ?

What could go wrong here ?

```
[displayString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", [sender tag]]];  
self.lblDisplay.text = displayString;
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say the mutable string is initiated with size 40?

Comment: Are you sure that the string is incorrect? Can you post the results of NSLog'ing displayString before and after appending the new tag?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO! 
You can try to log all your tags to determine where problem is.

```
NSLog(@"%d", [sender tag])
```

`Tag` property is NSInteger type, so you can use `%d` modifier instead of `%i`.
Also you can use `appendFormat` method:

```
[displayString appendFormat:@"%d",[sender tag]];
self.lblDisplay.text = displayString;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but just checked in debugger and sender tag is correct. At the eleventh entered digit, the last two digits began to change erratically and then , at the 13th click, a complete weird number is displayed !!!

Comment: tried again following your indications about %d instead of %i, and tried appendformat and yet no improvement.

Comment: self.displayString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: 40];

Comment: can you please list all your code, also please try to `init` `NSMutableString` without capacity?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `NSMutableString`?  Why not just do this:

`self.lblDisplay.text = [self.lblDisplay.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", [sender tag]];`

Anyway, how are you setting the tags?  Please post that code.  My guess is that something is going wrong there, not in passing the tag or appending the value.